# Masked SQL Query

Tags: sql

is there a function of some kind that can search by masked param?  example: pass a 5 char value XDWTR and return all rows that match any char. combinations from another table that has the masked values: **AW_, _CH**, **_DW, _DW**,____R.  my masked values are always 5 char.  this search would return 2 matches the _DW___ because the second and third DW match the second and third value of XDWTR.  the other ___DW_ starts in the 3rd pos. so it's not a match.  the ____R is a match because it's the last pos. that matches the R in XDWTR.

any helpful example would be great.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  How is `'AW_'` five characters?

Comment: In your examples, you need to match at least 2 letters or?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
where masked_param like concat('%', masked_value, '%')
```

If the masked values are really five characters, then the `concat()` is not necessary:

```
where masked_param like masked_value
```

This is using the fact that `_` is the escape character in `like` for any single character.